# Publisher policy restriction to Major.Minor?

Tags: .net, clr, versioning, .net-assembly

Why is the version number of publisher policies in .NET restricted to Major.Minor?

- If my Assembly 2.4.0.0 contains a bug
- and 2.4.1.0 fixes the bug
- and I install a publisher policy file for 2.4 (and not for 2.4.0.0)
- why does .NET still want to examine the publisher policy file when loading 2.4.26.0?

Is there any reason behind the restriction to Major.Minor?

Comment: It is a compromise, avoiding flooding the GAC with *lots* of policy files for frequent minor changes.  You simply replace the policy file when you deploy a minor bugfix.  You still have fine-grained control with the bindingRedirects.

Comment: I always have problems when framework developers make compromises which are not documented...but thanks for your information. If you like, you can transform it into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Publisher policy for version `2.4` applies to any version `2.4.X.Y` of an assembly. Version `2.4.26.0` also falls under the pattern `2.4.X.Y`, so publisher policy is examined when loading the assembly.

If you have defined your redirects like this:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.4.0.0" newVersion="2.4.1.0"/>
```

then when loading version `2.4.26.0` this policy will not be applied.